Can I add optional arrays to named functions in google sheets
Is there a way to specify one or more arrays an "optional array" in a named function in google sheets?
For example, with built in functions google provides
JOIN(delimiter, value_or_array1, [value_or_array2, …])

where the syntax [value_or_array2, …] uses the square brackets [ ] indicate optional additional values or arrays.
The function of these would then allow you to add more variables.
As an example, both =HSTACK(a1:b3,d1:d3) and =HSTACK(a1:b3,d1:d3) work. But creating a custom function named
MY_FUNCTION1 = HSTACK(array1,array2)

will limit the function HSTACK to only 2 variables and generate an error when using
MY_FUNCTION1(a1:b3,d1:d3,f1:f3)
>ERROR: Wrong number of arguments to MY_FUNCTION1. Expected 2 arguments, but got 3 arguments.

Is there a syntax that can be used to allow for optional arrays in custom functions?

there is no way to do this but there is very likely a workaround. If you share more details on what you're trying to do someone will help.

This question is similar to: Give the named function argument a default value if not specified. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
